# How to make this hard-coded file path dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, shell, autoit

The code should pass "File Path" in to the File Picker dialog window and upload/attach the file. I'm consistently getting an error.

VBA Code (error at Shell and asking for Object):

```
Sub AttachFile()
ufile = "D:\Desktop\Movement Pass.txt"
vbsFile = "D:\Downloads\Selenium Basic\Attachment.vbs"
Shell "WScript.exe " & vbsFile & " " & ufile 
End Sub
```

VB Script - Attachment.vbs (error at Arguments):

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Application.wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
Ret = WshShell.AppActivate("Open")
WshShell.Run "cmd.exe /c echo " & Wscript.Arguments(0) & "| clip", 0, True
WshShell.SendKeys "^{v}"
```

With AutoIt it worked for hard-coded file paths. I want the file path dynamically (so that I can run a loop from Excel VBA). Shell command does not compile and AutoIt does not allow dynamic paths in VBA.

I am looking for a solution in VBA and Shell command. AutoIt dynamic file path in VBA can be a solution too. I know this is not the right method but this is what I know:

```
VBA.Shell "Explorer D:\Seleninum\VB\Get_File_Name.exe", vbNormalFocus
```

Answer (score 0):

Paths passed as command line argument need to be quoted if they may contain spaces:

```
Sub AttachFile()
    ufile = "D:\Desktop\Movement Pass.txt"
    vbsFile = "D:\Downloads\Selenium Basic\Attachment.vbs"
    Shell "WScript.exe """ & vbsFile & """ """ & ufile & """"
End Sub
```